# Zod record alias to narrow type of key in nested record

Tags: typescript, zod

I have three simple types:

```js
const structureTypes = z.enum(["atom","molecule"])
const atomTypes = z.enum(["oxygen","hydrogen"])
const moleculeTypes = z.enum(["water","ammonia"])
```

I'm trying to create a type for a cache where the keys are the names of the atom or molecule, nested within the structure type, so the object shape would be e.g.:

```js
{
  atom: { oxygen: "abdshc7823", hydrogen: "hjksdfkjh" }
  molecule: { water: "hjfsdlkjj3", ammonia: "trewuivx67" }
}
```

I have almost got there by using Zod `record()` type:

```js
const structureIdCacheSchema = z.record(
  structureTypes,
  z.record(z.union([atomTypes, moleculeTypes]), z.string())
)
export type StructureIdCache = z.infer<typeof structureIdCacheSchema>
```

This produces a type that is very close, but the keys for the nested objects are not narrowed to the keys applicable to the structure, i.e. I could use `"water"` as a key for the `atom` object without error.

In typescript I would do something like the example below, where the alias `K` for the top-level key can be used to narrow the type for the nested key:

```js
export type StructureIdCache = {
  [K in keyof typeof structureTypes]: {
    [T in typeof structureTypes[K][number]]: string
  }
}
```

Is there a way to alias the key in a similar way with a Zod record?

Edit: I have also tried the suggested answer as below:

```
export const structureTypeCacheSchema = z.object({
  atom: z.record(atomTypeSchema, z.string()),
  molecule: z.record(moleculeTypeSchema, z.string()),
})
```

This has the minor downside of needing to be kept updated separately from the enums, but I'd be able to live with that. However, it also results in an error when I try to use the type because I can't index the second-level element:

```
export const getTypeId = async (
  type: Structure,
  name: AtomType | MoleculeType
): Promise<string> => {
const existingIdCache: StructureIdCache | null = await cache.get(
    `typeIds`,
    "json"
  )
  if (existingIdCache && existingIdCache[type][name]) {
    return existingIdCache[type][name]
  }
```

gives the error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"oxygen" | "hydrogen" | "water" | "ammonia"' can't be used to index type 'Partial<Record<"paragraph" | "oxygen" | "hydrogen", string>> | Partial<...>'.
  Property 'oxygen' does not exist on type 'Partial<Record<"oxygen" | "hydrogen", string>> | Partial<...>'.ts(7053)
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do what you're looking for

```
const structureIdCacheSchema = z.object({
  atom: z.record(atomTypes, z.string()),
  molecule: z.record(moleculeTypes, z.string())
})

export type StructureIdCache = z.infer<typeof structureIdCacheSchema>
```

Comment: This means having to keep two separate places updated when the `structureTypes` change - there are many more of them than shown in the example above, hence wanting to do this programmatically and only keep 1 object as the source of truth.

Comment: You would need some object to tell it which structure type corresponds to which enum. You might be able to do something with an object and mapping it into the object here, but Zod might not like that. Plus, at that point, you might as well just do this.